# USB devices (keyboard, mouse, hub) connectivity/ recognition issue due to Power Surge

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, microsoft-surface, usb-hub

I recently encountered connectivity/recognition issue with my set of keyboard, mouse and hub. I have some Dell genuine keyboards, used with different computers/laptops running various OS (UbuntuMATE 16.04, Windows 7, Windows 8.1, Android). Unlike the other keyboards of mine having the first light green, the damaged keyboard now shows only green light, the light closest to the smart card slot when connecting.

**TL;DR description**:

- 1 set of keyboard, mouse and hub were destroyed/damaged by power surge on usb connection issue. (strangely, the power bank was connected to the micro USB not the USB 3.0 port where those devices were hooked into; the exceeding power the Surface 3 non-Pro feels was transmitted to those devices, causing them to hang-over, maybe?).

**Tested**:

- That set no longer works on any OS distro, computer I have. (I tried plugged in, unplugged, replugged many times and on different time; on Windows OS I tried fixing usb issue by uninstalling the USB controller driver too, [Device Manager], but that doesn't help). Other keyboards and mouses I have work fine.

**Issue reproduction**:

- using a microUSB power bank 300,000mAh on Surface 3 resulted in power surge on usb hubs (repetitively alerted on the taskbar).
- The keyboard, mouse and DVD RW drive are all connected to a multiport USB hub, and that hub was connected to my Surface 3 through USB 3.0 port.

[solar, AC charging, DC out 300,000mAh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlBiS.jpg)

## **Questions**:

- Do I lose that set permanently? (no functionality, no usability since there is silence and no sign of recognition/connectivity when hooking them to USB ports on any other device/OS I have).
- What is the cause? Can such power surge on usb port damage the devices? Why power surge on microUSB port destroyed the devices hooked to ANOTHER regular USB 3.0 port?
- Is the cause likely to be circuit breakage inside those devices and potentially to fixable but they have to be soldered?
- Any similar encounter/experience from you? any suggestion on how to fix? The entire set being damaged cost me 50 bucks already.

Thank you and best regards,

Pristine.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I lose that set permanently? (no functionality, no usability since there is silence and no sign of recognition/connectivity when hooking them to USB ports on any other device/OS I have).

Based on your tests on different equipment, it appears they are indeed defective.

> What is the cause? Can such power surge on usb port damage the devices? Why power surge on microUSB port destroyed the devices hooked to ANOTHER regular USB 3.0 port?

As you probably realize, the circuitry inside the computer is all connected together, making it possible for a single device malfunction to damage other components.

> Is the cause likely to be circuit breakage inside those devices and potentially to fixable but they have to be soldered?

A power surge doesn't normally cause solders to melt, and if they do it's because of extreme heat that **certainly** destroyed other components.  It would more typically ruin micro chips including memory banks.

> Any similar encounter/experience from you? any suggestion on how to fix? The entire set being damaged cost me 50 bucks already.

It would cost more to get a specialist to look at it, let alone repair them, than to replace the whole set.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I bet the micro ships in those usb devices of mine are damaged. I can however, reuse my USB hub for charging several phones of mine, power still go through fine. Problem with the USB hub is hooking a USB data storage (USB key, the French calls it clé de USB) to a PC through the hub, the PC can't recognise the USB key; connecting without the hub is fine.

Comment: Right.  That's not surprising since the charging circuit is most likely a direct connection that doesn't depend on the USB hub functionality handled by the (probably) damaged built-in chip.

Comment: thanks, Will that still damage my phones or other devices, using only usb ports from that USB Hub for charging only, hopefully only about around 2A-5Amp provided by the Hub?.  I bought the power bank from Aliexpress, most likely Hongkong-China marketplace. While the Chinese markets it as solar, AC charging, DC out 300,000mAh; I doubt it is that high. I've looked at some power banks available on Amazon and Ebay, 12000-27000mAh is as big as a 2.5"-3.5" external HDD. So, I don't that the likely same size (3.5") can boat such a huge capacity (of 10x times).

Comment: The main problem was connecting it to a grounded equipment, but may possibly cause an imbalance in the battery charges though.  As you possibly know, a voltage is a difference of potential between the positive and negative connectors, but if the negative connector is not at 0V (or near it) from the actual ground, it may cause a reverse current or an overload, which could have caused your mess in the first place.